# How to perform dynamic port forwarding in rust?

Tags: rust, ssh, portforwarding

I'm pretty new to rust and I'd like to create a small automation app which involves using dynamic port forwarding with ssh.

Let's say I have Computer A , B and C. computer A is my laptop, B is a pass through server and Computer C is my target. Until now I had a huge succession of things to do manually and I want to automate it, so I had to do ,

```
ComputerA ~$ ssh -D 1080 myUser@ComputerB ; ./myActionOns ComputerC:8888 ; ...
```

I'd like to know how to perform the same with rust , I looked through ssh2-rs and thrussh but I can't seem to find any methods to do so.

Does anyone know how ?

PS:
I can't make any changes to the Computer B the server doesn't belong to me only the computer A and C are mine and computer B owner allows me to perform only ssh.

EDIT:
some comments made me realize I needed to add some details, I want to do this in rust because I wanna learn with projects. I don't own the network infrastructure and the owner only allows me to connect to some pc using the ssh passthrough (ComputerB) computerC can actually be a list of multiple computers. my goal is to perform in rust something like this in python: https://github.com/mrluaf/SSH-Tunnel-Dynamic-Port-Forwarding-Python. I'm adding a picturing showing in red what I can't change, my goal is to get a binary I can share that is a all in one solution for my friends.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the technical challenge you are facing, and which part of the process do you wish to replace -- it seems like the the command to start the connection is only one command right now, so it's unclear to me how wrapping ssh inside a Rust executable would be helpful

Comment: Managing tunnel opening and closing through command process and PID, is a possibility but is really complicated to handle, I'd like to know if there exist a crate that can manage ssh client side with the support of dynamic port forwarding. or if there is an easier way to achieve my goal which is to be able to perform multiple task on my target machine which can involve multiple port through a pass-through server in rust.

Comment: Can you not do `ssh -L 1234:localhost:5555 ComputerB ssh -D 5555 -N ComputerC`? This command would start dynamic port forwarding on ComputerB which forwards to ComputerC, and open a static port for SOCKS on ComputerA, which forwards the SOCKS connection to ComputerB. If the tunnel fails on any machine, the tunnel stops on all machines, so running this in a loop on the host should be sufficient. I'm not really understanding how Rust or any program or custom handling could improve this

Comment: I just got issues with managing the tunnel if I spawn in with a std::process:command. And I want my program to create and close the tunnel by itself without action from the user

Comment: Why do you need to involve computer B at all? Why can't you establish a VPN between A and C directly? There are many mature VPN options.

Comment: I don't own the network which C is on so I can't deploy a vpn on where C is also it is a schema, I'm just trying to make dynamic port forwarding with ssh in rust , like this in python https://github.com/mrluaf/SSH-Tunnel-Dynamic-Port-Forwarding-Python